# Extrapolate letters from blurred writing (e.g. license plate)?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, ocr

My friend has a blurred image of a thief's license plate. Is it possible to run an algorithm on these pixels to determine the most likely characters that the pixels represent?

(The fact that it's a license plate is irrelevant, the solution should work by principle on  any photographed text that is difficult to decipher.)

Please help me find my dog!

Update: My friend sent my two still images, they are very poor. He doesn't have any shots of the license plates unfortunately.

Image 1:
[An image of the van. I'm trying to decipher the text above the word 'rentals'.](http://www.sugarpitch.com/van_front.png)

Image 2:
[This is the same van, with presumably the same text. It's in the upper right-hand corner of the image](http://www.sugarpitch.com/van_side.png)

Comment: Thanks for the offer, I'm not sure about the legality of that though.

Comment: Could you post one letter or two? ie. not enough to actually identify the entire license plate but enough to show us what you're dealing with? Make sure you don't post it as jpeg though, or you'll introduce further degradation. PNG is a good choice.

Comment: If you want specific help you probably need someone to look at the photograph. If you trust one of us that have a public profile here, you might ask someone to look at it without publishing it. I would be willing to do that. My email is in my profile.

Comment: Thanks people for your offer of help.Check out the photos in the original post. Unfortunately, I don't think there's enough information. I already called the police, there's not a lot of work they can use on this though.

Comment: How about a search of local van/removal companies etc specific to your area. See if the logo matches any van pictures on their website

Answer (score 1):

It depends on why/how it's blurred. There are a number of things you could try though: one would be a simple sharpening with an unsharp mask. Another I've found surprisingly effective at times is to simply invert the colors in a photo -- sometimes things that are really hard to read normally just pop right out when inverted.

For a one-time task like this, however, you probably want to use existing tools (e.g., Photoshop or The Gimp), rather than writing new code. It'll take a long time and a lot of effort to match what they already have just waiting to be used.

Comment: Yes, these are all worthwhile approaches. I saw somebody using channels as well to accentuate the characters.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Using a pseudo-color filter might be of use, also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False-color

Answer (score 1):

Play with Photoshop. Try different sharpening filters, in different strengths and different orders. Also play with posterization. Revert to the original image frequently. Look for what works. Use your eyes. If you can't see the answer (after applying filters), OCR probably won't either.

Comment: Yes, I don't have the image myself at the moment, but your approach makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Motion blur can be removed, because all of the information is still in the photograph. But in this case, I'm not sure any form of image processing is going to help.

I apologize if you already tried this, but have you looked through the "rentals" section of the phone book to see if you can find a company with a similar logo? I assume this is a van from a rental equipment or "rent-to-own" business, not a car rental agency.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a sharpening, followed by Sobel filter to find edges, then perform your OCR on it.

Refs:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator

http://www.bythom.com/sharpening.htm

Comment: OCR is surely not the best way to guess the blurred chars :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not familiar with this area (algorithms). Is the Sobel filter something that existing software will let me apply on the image, or do I have to incorporate the algorithm myself into custom code?

Comment: @belisarius: Well, I think that OCR isn't probably the best method - basically just looking at it would be better. I noticed the OCR term in the tags, so I thought perhaps the author wanted to use an automated approach.

Comment: @Conor: I'd use something like the GIMP: http://www.gimp.org/ It's free and open source, so you'd be able to extend it if you really needed to do so, but I think probably you'll find the necessary tools at your disposal already bundled with the product.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is possible under ideal conditions. But it requires that you know the transform from the original to the blurred image.

Image compression, non-linearities in the camera, limited resolution and noise may get in the way. If you're lucky a standard photoshop sharpening filter will do.

Comment: Yes, it was a CCTV shot taken at night - all the negative factors you mentioned are probably plaguing my friend's efforts.